# wandb.plot.line does not work and it just shows a table

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, wandb

I used this example that was provided by WandB. However, the web interface just shows a table instead of a figure.

```
data = [[i, random.random() + math.sin(i / 10)] for i in range(100)]
        table = wandb.Table(data=data, columns=["step", "height"])
        wandb.log({'line-plot1': wandb.plot.line(table, "step", "height")})
```

This is a screenshot from WandB's web interface:
[image]

Also, I have the same problem with other kinds of figures and charts that use a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> X-Post from the wandb forum

https://community.wandb.ai/t/wandb-plot-confusion-matrix-just-show-a-table/1744

If you click the section called “Custom Charts” above the Table, it’ll show the line plot that you’ve logged.

Logging the Table also is expected behaviour, because this will allow users to interactively explore the logged data in a W&B Table after logging it.